# JavaEE Globally Catch Runtime exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to "globally" catch a Runtime exception, now this sounds silly right but let me explain.
I have created a interceptor that I use on all my ejbs which require authorization to use, this interceptor is called every time a method is called.

See here the code:

```
@Secure
@Interceptor
public class SecurityInterceptor {

    @EJB
    private SessionManager sessionManager;

    @AroundInvoke
    private Object securityCheck(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hello");
        List<UserGroup> allowedRoles = (List<UserGroup>) ctx.getContextData().get("rolesAllowed");
        sessionManager.isAuthorized(allowedRoles);
        return ctx.proceed();
    }
}
```

Now I don't want in my Named Bean to surround the body of every method that uses one of these secured beans with a try and catch block, like this:

```
public List<Contracts> getContracts() {
    List<Contracts> contracts = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        contracts = contractEntityManager.getAll();
    } catch (EJBTransactionRolledbackException e) {
        Throwable throwable = ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e);
        if (throwable instanceof NotAuthenticatedException) {
            System.out.println("Not Authenticated");
        }
        else if (throwable instanceof UnAuthorizedException) {
            System.out.println("Not Authorized");
        }
    }
    return contracts;
}
```

So is there some way to globally catch a runtime exception and the redirect the user to the login page if he is unauthenticated and to a error page when he is unauthorized.

Maybe my design is just generally bad and I would need to complety rethink this idea.
Please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: So basically you are asking if you can add a try catch block to your interceptor code?

Comment: No I want my interceptor to throw this exception since in the web tier (named bean etc..) I want to redirect the user to a login page or error page. Or can I do that also in the Server tier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in the end, it is the in the web tier that you want to catch the exceptions. This is easy:

- If you are only on servlets, specify the `error-page` element in web.xml for each exception you wish to handle, e.g. as follows:

  ```xml
  <error-page>
      <exception-type>fully.quallified.NotAuthenticatedException</exception-type>
      <location>/where/to/redirect/eg/login</location>
  </error-page>
  ```

  You declare the exception you want to handle globally and the URL you want to handle it, it may be a servlet, a JSP or any other resource.
- JAX-RS offers a similar mechanism with the `javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper`:

  ```xml
  @Provider
  public class NotAuthenticatedExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotAuthenticatedException> {
      ...
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much the error page tag was what I was looking for. Although I had to use Omnifaces FacesExceptionFilter because some of the exceptions were wrapped in a FacesException. Also I had to annotate my exceptions on the ejb level as @ApplicationException also to avoid wrapping of the exception :)